# Outlook 2013 VBA code Not Seeing Active Reply Email

Tags: vba, outlook

I have used the following code in Outlook 2010 successfully:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim myItem As MailItem
    Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem


    If InStr(1, myItem.Subject, "@gtd") > 0 Then
        Dim objMe As Recipient
        Set objMe = Item.Recipients.Add("mikemahony.f760c@m.evernote.com")
        ' for testing only -- Set objMe = Item.Recipients.Add("mike.mahony@outlook.com")
        objMe.Type = olBCC
        objMe.Resolve
        Set objMe = Nothing
    End If
    Set myItem = Nothing
End Sub

Sub GTDTracking()
    Dim initialSubj As String
    Dim finalSubj As String
    Dim myItem As MailItem
    Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    initialSubj = myItem.Subject
    finalSubj = initialSubj & " (@gtd)"
    myItem.Subject = finalSubj
End Sub
```

I have recently switched to Outlook 2013. It offers the option to hit reply and have the new reply window be docked right in the message list. However, if I reply that way my code fails at this line:

```
Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
```

If I open up the message by double-clicking so it is not docked to the message list, the code runs just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what worked for me. The following function returns an `Outlook.MailItem` message object for the message the user is looking at, whether it is a docked reply or a message in its own window. If it can't find an open message, then it will return `Nothing`. The key to the whole thing is the `Application.ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse` property, which is new in Outlook 2013. You will have to add some code to avoid attempting to call `ActiveInlineResponse` if you are running an older version of Outlook.

```
Function getActiveMessage() As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim insp As Outlook.Inspector

    If TypeOf Application.ActiveWindow Is Outlook.Inspector Then
        Set insp = Application.ActiveWindow
    End If


    If insp Is Nothing Then
        Dim inline as Object
        Set inline = Application.ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse
        If inline Is Nothing Then Exit Function

        Set getActiveMessage = inline
    Else
       Set insp = Application.ActiveInspector
       If insp.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
          Set getActiveMessage = insp.CurrentItem
       Else
         Exit Function
       End If

    End If

End Function
```

Let me know if it works for you!